# Check real time connectivity in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need your help or suggestion.

How to monitor real time connectivity between two SQL Server machines if I want to doing synchronization data between those two servers?

Simple illustration : I want to transfer data from one table in first database to the same table in second database but if the connectivity is down, all the transaction will be aborted.

Thanks for your kindly help.

regards,

Ricky

Comment: So, [server A needs to know if the connection to server B is active] or are you trying to monitor the connection between those servers, from a third machine?

Comment: The first one, server A needs to know if the connection to server B is active.